# Forever List won't show up in Crontab output, but shows up when run from command line

Tags: bash, centos, cron, forever

I have a bash script that saves the output of `forever list` to a string, does some manipulation and saves it to an XML file. In the same file, I'm also calling the shell command `uptime`. The file is housed at `/var/www/html/ytca/rss.sh`. If I execute that command, the file is updated correctly. I have a cron job running:

`*/2 * * * * /var/www/html/ytca/rss.sh`

And created using the `crontab -e` command under root, and nothing shows up with the `forever list` command, but things show up with the `uptime` command.

Here is everything you might need:

**rss.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date`
RESULT=`/usr/local/bin/forever list | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"`
OTHER=$(/usr/local/bin/forever list)
upt=`uptime`
String='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Server Details</title>
<link>http://www.google.com/</link>
<description>Server details for Chris</description>
<item>
<title> Updated: '$DATE'</title>
<link>www.google.com</link>
<guid>abc123</guid>
<pubDate>'$DATE'</pubDate>
<description><![CDATA[Service uptime: '$RESULT';<br/>DbServer uptime: '$OTHER';<br/>Server uptime: '${upt:0:23}']]></description>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>'
echo $String > '/var/www/html/ytca/site/update.xml'
```

**which forever:**

```
/usr/local/bin/forever
```

Cutting out some unnecessary junk:

**output when run from command line:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ...<![CDATA[Service uptime: info: Forever processes running data: uid command... 0:0:23:31.723 ;<br/>DbServer uptime: [32minfo[39m: Forever processes running [9...3:31.932[39m ;<br/>Server uptime: 00:02:57 up 4 days, 48]]></description> </item> </channel> </rss>
```

**output when run from cron:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...<![CDATA[Service uptime: ;<br/>DbServer uptime: ;<br/>Server uptime: 00:00:01 up 4 days, 45]]></description> </item> </channel> </rss>
```

I've been working on this for hours, it just doesn't seem to make sense. I've tried just echoing out the forever list in a crontab, and it ends up blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin/` in your `root's` `PATH`?

Comment: Check the output of `OTHER=$(/usr/local/bin/forever list)`.  Seems that the `forever` process wasn't even running when you executed via cron.

Comment: @devnull Forever is running and has been running for weeks, and because I can execute the .sh file via command and it updates correctly the problem is not that forever list doesn't work, it's that it specifically isn't working when being called from cron.

Comment: @JS웃 yes, here is what I get when I echo $PATH: 
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/bin

Comment: @ChrisJones Does cron run as the same user that is able to execute the script successfully from the command line?

Comment: @devnull I run the commands as root, and I've tried many combinations that should all allow the cron to run as root. I've done `crontab -e` as root, I've added `root` to the actual cronjob in the optional user field, I've tried adding the command directly to `/etc/crontab`, both with and without the `root` user explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

The forever process is probably bound to a user. Try executing `rss.sh` as the user from cron:

```
*/2 * * * * su - <user> -c /var/www/html/ytca/rss.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your file as executable

```
chmod a+x /var/www/html/ytca/rss.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

So after trying for a couple of hours and not finding anything suitable on the net ; the solution actually turned out to be quite simple . 
Add the output of `which forever` to your $PATH variable excluding "forever" which in my case would be /usr/local/bin .

```
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/
    cmd=`forever list`
    echo $cmd > /home/muzammil/foreverlist.log
```

will give you the correct output while

```
    cmd=`/usr/local/bin/forever list`
    echo $cmd > /home/muzammilm/foreverlist.log
```

gave me a null file.

Also for some strange reason even though my $PATH variable already contains "/usr/local/bin" it doesn't work , but only works when explicitly mentioned within the shell script itself.